# Is it possible to update SubscriberLists from different child Business Units in one Subscriber

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I need to update SubscriberLists from different child Business Units. To do that I create Subscriber and put SubscriberLists inside of it. How can I specify ClientId of Business Unit for every SubscriberList?

**UPDATE**

I'm trying to update it with following code and I don't know how to set clientId for every SubscriberList in for loop:

```
SET @sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
SetObjectProperty(@sub,"SubscriberKey", QUERYPARAMETER('key'))

FOR @d = 1 TO RowCount(@sublistArray) DO
    SET @listRow = Row(@sublistArray, @d)
    SET @listId = Field(@listRow, 1)

    SET @list = CreateObject("SubscriberList")
    SetObjectProperty(@list,"ID", @listId)
    SetObjectProperty(@list,"IDSpecified", "true")
    SetObjectProperty(@list,"Status", @listStatus)
    SetObjectProperty(@list,"StatusSpecified", "true")
    AddObjectArrayItem(@sub,"Lists", @list)
NEXT @d

Set @update_list_sub = InvokeUpdate(@sub, @update_sub_status, @update_sub_errorcode)
```

Comment: How are you making these updates - you've tagged AMPscript so assuming this is with AMPscript on a landing page. Do you have any code to work from?

Comment: @AnonWonderer updated question

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine - you will just need an additional statement to specify a child ID property and to populate that with the MID of the specific business unit. Try this within your code:

```
   SET @client = CreateObject("ClientID")
   SetObjectProperty(@client, "ID", [Insert MID of specific BU here])
   SetObjectProperty(@client, "IDSpecified", "true")
   SetObjectProperty(@sub, "Client", @client)
```

Comment: Yes, I did it, but that way I will need to create Subscriber for every clientId. I wanted to avoid it, specify clientId for every SubscriberList and update it with one query